# Android: show ContextMenu on longPress for a view?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I a view have for which I would like to show a ContextMenu on a longPress. I was able to get this ContextMenu to display using the recommended method of: calling activity.registerForContextmenu and overriding onCreateContextMenu(...).

However, I would like to do other things on other touch events, so my view has a TouchHandler assigned to it.  When this touch handler is set, the onCreateContextMenu() never gets called (presumably because my TouchHandler is eating the longPress).  So, is there anyway for me to instantiate and show a ContextMenu without the onCreateContenxtMenu() method being called?

Alternatively, I could just show my own custom dialog with my "menu" items.  Is there any disadvantage to using a custom dialog instead of the ContextMenu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to try, is to return false from your [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) if you don't want the event to be consumed.

Comment: I return the result of my GestureDetector, the longPress method of which has return type of "void"

Comment: returning false from the onDown() method of my GestureDector allows the context menu to display.

Answer (score 1):

What do you return from [OnTouchListener.OnTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)? Returning `false` means you haven't consumed the event, which should mean that other actions can be peformed on it as well.

Comment: I return the result of my GestureDetector, the longPress method of which has return type of "void"